# How do I prevent an AngularJS route from trying to reauthenticate with my server side SSO?

Tags: angularjs, single-sign-on

I have set up an AngularJS application that uses the following routing configuration on the module:

```
$stateProvider.
    state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'public/modules/core/views/home.client.view.html'
    }).
    state('page2', {    
        url: '/test',
        templateUrl: 'public/modules/core/views/test.client.view.html'
    });
```

My webserver has SSO software on it that forces me to login and if authorized, will set user information on the request headers and forward me to the requesting page.  So, when first hitting the application (http://---.-------.com), I logon and get redirected to the home page above.  Angular works just fine and loads the right template.  However, when clicking on a link on the page pointing to /test (the second template to load), it tries to reauthenticate for some reason and I get a cross domain exception in the browser console.

I thought AngularJS would load the second template when I clicked on the link without a page reload so that the server side SSO wouldn't retrigger.  When I embedded the template in the initial html file, I was able to load the template without any issues, but I plan on having many templates and would like to keep the templates separated in their own files.

Can anyone see how I can keep the templates in their own files, but prevent the SSO from being triggered on every AngularJS re-route?

----- Clarification:  So, after the initial sign on, a cookie is provided.  Maybe I just don't understand how to get Angular ui-router to use that cookie, which should be part of subsequent requests.  How is this typically done?

Comment: Please clarify a couple of things: does the second view interact with the backend in some way? For instance, does it use the $http service to make a request to the server? Also, what do you mean by embedding the template in the initial html file? How are you including your views in the page? Are you using the ng-view directive?

Comment: @Tavio The second view does not make any requests to the server right now (although it will eventually).  It is just simple html code.  When I embedded the template in the initial html file, I meant I placed <script type="text/ng-template" id="..."> HTML HERE </script> in the initial file.  Then I changed the templateUrl to the id value, and it just loaded when the link was clicked.  And I am using <div data-ui-view> (in the initial html file) for the container of the templates.  I do make a request for data on the / (home) view and it allows it.

Comment: I see. I have never used angular in this way (I use the ng-view directive and keep my views in separate html files which are in turn referenced by $routeProvider). I hope somebody else will be able to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely to be problem with your server configuration, unless you have special JS code to manipulate the request (e.g. Angular request interceptors). I use `$stateProvider` in the same way as you and mine just worked well.

One possibility is your server has been configured to force authentication each time when an `HTML` page is requested. It's easy to check out - after you logon, refresh the current page. If you are asked to logon again, that's the problem.

The solution depends on your sever technology. A workaround is to rename *test.client.view.html* to *test.client.view.**js*** and update the `templateUrl`, since your js loading seems fine.

This is my best guess without further detail. Hope it helps.